# How to modify javascript array of objects like object values as key value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, data-structures

I am new to JavaScript programming and react. I have a data structure which I converted using the array.reduce method to the below given array.

My objective is to get the array re-structured in-order to use this is in a chart to visualize the data using react chart js 2.

```
const charData = [
    {
        "year": "2020",
        "value": [
            {
                "levelName": "Platinum",
                "yearlyCount": "1074"
            },
            {
                "levelName": "Gold",
                "yearlyCount": "1847"
            },
            {
                "levelName": "Silver",
                "yearlyCount": "4804"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

i need the below structure

```
[
{
"year": "2020",
"Platinum": "1074",
"Gold": "1847",
"silver": "4804"
}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `map` with `reduce`

```js
const charData =  [
    {
        "year": "2020",
        "value": [
            {
                "levelName": "Platinum",
                "yearlyCount": "1074"
            },
            {
                "levelName": "Gold",
                "yearlyCount": "1847"
            },
            {
                "levelName": "Silver",
                "yearlyCount": "4804"
            }
        ]
    }
]

const res = charData.map(item => {
  const subRes = item.value.reduce((acc,i) => {
    return {
     ...acc,
     [i.levelName]  : i.yearlyCount
     
    }
  }, {})
  
  return {
    year: item.year,
    ...subRes,
  }
  
})

console.log(res)
```